# Click on card then navigate to card page details in react

Tags: reactjs

I created a page and show some card also some little details of cards
Now I want to click on any card navigate to this on show all details 
How can I get to this page on react js ?
Is this need to Redux ?

Comment: can you show what you currently have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of **Redux** for your issue.

You just use **React-router**. you just create two component 1. **Cards.js**, 2. **CardDetails.js** and navigate to card details on click event of cards in Card.js

**Cards.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";


class Cards extends React.Component {

goToCarddetails = (cardId) => {
    localStorage.setItem("selectedCard", cardId);
    this.props.history.push('/card-details');
// you can manage here to pass the clicked card id to the card details page if needed
}

render() {
    return ( <div>
        <div onClick = {()=>this.goToCarddetails('cardId1')}> card 1 </div>
        <div onClick = {()=>this.goToCarddetails('cardId2')}> card 2 </div>
        <div onClick = {()=>this.goToCarddetails('cardId3')}> card 3 </div>
       </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Cards);
```

With above on clicking any card you will be navigated to card details page.

**CardDetails.js**

```
import React from "react";


class CardDetails extends React.Component {

render() {
    let selectedCardId = localStorage.getItem("selectedCard");
    // you can get this cardId anywhere in the component as per your requirement 
    return ( <div>
        card details here
       </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CardDetails;
```

***Note :***  I'm using **react-router 4** here in example.

Comment: thanks. but how to select id by click? i fetch data of any card from server side and then use map function how to pass data of card to this view?

Comment: you can pass `cardId` to `cardDetails.js` in many ways ...
1.  **query parameter** 
2.   **path parameter** 
3.  **localStorage** 
-4.  if you are using redux the with **reducer**.

explaining the simplest way here **localStorage** by editing above example.

Comment: have you ever pass state with react router?

Comment: you mean a complete object ?

Comment: if you are using redux you can get the store data in the props in any component.

But if you want to pass the local state data from **cards.js** and not using redux you can use the above way (**localStorage**) to pass data. but to pass an object with localStorage, you have to stringify and parse the object with `JSON.stringify(cardData)` before setItem in **cards.js** and JSON.parse(cardData) after getItem in **cardDetails.js**

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand what you said completely, but you can use React-Router to navigate to different pages in Reactjs. To install it using npm, go to your Application directory and enter in command line **npm install --save React-Router**

Here is a simple code to navigate to different pages:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";


const Home=()=>
 (<div>
  <h2>Home</h2>
 </div>
);

const About=()=>
(<div>
  <h2>About</h2>
   </div>
 );


class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return (
  <Router>
    <div>

        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>




      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
      );
    }
  }
export default App;
```

I hope it helped...